# CORS errors in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, webdav

I'm using [webdav library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdav) inside a react application. As of now, I'm in an early stage of development and I'm just logging the results of a call that should list the contents of a directory. To do that I just created a method that instantiates the client and makes an ls of the directories and then logs them in the console.

```
 const getItems = async() => {
  const client = createClient(
    "https://mywebdavurl.com/",
    {
        authType: AuthType.Password,
        username: "user",
        password: "passwd",
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
        }
    }
  );
  console.log(client)
  const directoryItems = await client.getDirectoryContents("/");
  console.log(directoryItems);
}

function App() {
  getItems()

  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={ROUTES.HOME}>
          Hello Sputnik
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

When I open the app on the browser (localhost) using Chrome, I receive some strange errors that I can't fix.
[Network tab in the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0efc8.jpg)
First of all, I can't fix the CORS problem. I tried adding the headers but the result will not change and I will receive this error in my console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mywebdavurl.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I tried, just for debugging purposes to use a Chrome Extension that disables the CORS. If I use this, the error is quite different and says:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mywebdavurl.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Well, if you look at the image, you can see that I have both a CORS problem and an Unauthorized problem. If I check my WebDAV server logs they state this:

> 2021/10/21 13:44:03 [error] 12#0: *106 no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: 100.70.4.1, server: , request: "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1", host: "https://mywebdavurl.com/", referrer: "http://localhost:3001/ "
> 2021/10/21 13:44:14 [error] 12#0: *106 no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: 100.70.4.1, server: , request: "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1", host: "https://mywebdavurl.com/", referrer: "http://localhost:3001/ "
> 2021/10/21 13:44:14 [error] 12#0: *105 no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: 100.64.6.1, server: , request: "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1", host: "https://mywebdavurl.com/", referrer: "http://localhost:3001/ "
> 2021/10/21 13:49:20 [error] 12#0: *109 no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: 100.70.6.1, server: , request: "OPTIONS /results/ HTTP/1.1", host: "https://mywebdavurl.com/", referrer: "http://localhost:3001/ "
> 2021/10/21 13:49:20 [error] 12#0: *110 no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: 100.64.8.1, server: , request: "OPTIONS /results/ HTTP/1.1", host: "https://mywebdavurl.com/", referrer: "http://localhost:3001/ "

If I check the contents of the request and responses from the network tab in the inspector, I get the following:

**Requests with type XHR and status CORS error**

```
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Provisional headers are shown
Learn more
Accept: text/plain
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd2Q=
Depth: 1
Referer: http://localhost:3001/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36
```

**Requests with type Preflight and status 401**

```
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: 10.107.50.24:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
access-control-allow-headers: *
access-control-allow-methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-expose-headers: *
Connection: close
Content-Length: 605
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 21 Oct 2021 11:44:14 GMT
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie: d8522de4f35024212f5d0e7f0b289d29=3570640034998b52c04921bcd836972d; path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted"
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,de-DE;q=0.9,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-headers,access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin,authorization,depth
Access-Control-Request-Method: PROPFIND
Connection: keep-alive
Host: https://mywebdavurl.com/
Origin: http://localhost:3001
Referer: http://localhost:3001/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36
```

From what I can see, the XHR requests have the CORS headers and the Authorization header. Yet I receive the CORS error. The preflight request, instead, is not filled with those headers.

In the end, I tried one last thing that gave me, once again an unexpected result: I open Chrome using the following command-line flags:

```
C:\Users\Francesco\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp
```

When I do that, everything works fine. Of course, the codebase is the same. In this case, I have in the network tab in Chrome just two entries (same values, maybe I'm doing something wrong in the way a make the call) with the following data:

Type: XHR

Status: 207

```
Request Method: PROPFIND
Status Code: 207 Multi-Status
Remote Address: 10.107.50.24:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 21 Oct 2021 12:44:55 GMT
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept: text/plain
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,de-DE;q=0.9,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd2Q=
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: d8522de4f35024212f5d0e7f0b289d29=3570640034998b52c04921bcd836972d
Depth: 1
Host: https://mywebdavurl.com/
Referer: http://localhost:3001/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36
```

Of course, I need to get rid of this hack that was just for debugging purposes and let me understand that I can use the WebDAV library inside a react application and that there are some other kinds of problems.

Any help will be appreciated. I provided all the information I have but if you need more, I can look for other stuff.

Comment: CORS errors can only be fixed by the server, not client.

Comment: make proxy on your server. your client call to your server, your sever call to dest and return data to your client.

Comment: @Evert when you talk about the server, do you mean the server that serves the react application (localhost:3001) or the WebDAV server? Sorry for the stupid question but I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: @Robert unfortunately this is not possible as of now because one of the requirements is that the client should call webdav without talking to an "intermediate" server.

Comment: So you can call it by proxy sever witch will add header. I made somitng like this in past with wolframalfpa api.  There is a lot of free proxy server but if you need stable one probably better will be pay.

Comment: What puzzles me is why everything works when the original poster disabled security in Chrome with the command line parameter "disable-web-security".

Comment: @Robert I cannot also do that. I have been required to use this WebDAV client directly from the react app to avoid an intermediate layer, as I said. Making a small proxy server on my own or using another one is the same... Moreover, I have already added the headers. So I expect them to be in the request...

Comment: This is a security feature. If you could add the headers on the client, it would be useless. Only the WebDAV server can add CORS headers.